# Play Store is disabled on a pre-installed GS android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I created a new virtual device from AVD manager and I selected the one with a pre-installed Play Store.

But when I opened it, there was no store there.? I opened the details window of the virtual device and I found this line `PlayStore.enabled: false` ? why is it false, should it be true? and can I enable it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you got it fixed? If so please share the answer, I am only suffering from above

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya still happening, I had to use Genymotion for now..

Comment: Thanks, But Genymotion is not free isn't it ?

Comment: The personal license is free, but make sure to install GAPPS to use google apps and services. see the steps in the link => https://ask.ericlin.info/post/2017/08/genymotion-now-comes-with-open-gapps-installer/

Answer (score 2):

Odd that I'm posting an answer to a 2 year old question...

The problem is your target system image. It needs to specify **(Google Play)**.

For example: Target | **Android 11.0 (Google Play)**